# Response callback on a different thread

Tags: multithreading, callback, restsharp

Is the Callback supposed to be called on a different thread?
Using this code:

```
client.ExecuteAsync<List<IngredientDto>>(request, Response =>
    {
        textBox1.Text += Response.Data.Count;
    });
```

I get a "InvalidOperationException":

> "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Shouldn't the callback be on the UI thread, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you look at source code, you'll see

```
    public virtual RestRequestAsyncHandle ExecuteAsync<T>(IRestRequest request, Action<IRestResponse<T>, RestRequestAsyncHandle> callback)
    {
        return ExecuteAsync(request, (response, asyncHandle) =>
        {
            IRestResponse<T> restResponse = response as RestResponse<T>;
            if (response.ResponseStatus != ResponseStatus.Aborted)
            {
                restResponse = Deserialize<T>(request, response);
            }

            callback(restResponse, asyncHandle);//<--- this means that response & callback are executed at **same** thread.
        });
    }
```

That leads to:
You can't update ui objects from non-ui thread. In case of WPF you can use `Dispatcher`

```
client.ExecuteAsync<List<IngredientDto>>(request, Response =>
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)() => {textBox1.Text += Response.Data.Count;});
    });
```

In general case see [syncronization context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx)

Comment: I know, but shouldn't the callback be called on the UI thread? Isn't the actual process on another thread, and then notify the caller on the UI thread?

Comment: See my update. Callback is called on the same thread that request is.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a question on why the RestSharp team worked this way. For example: if I was to use BackgroundWorker, the DoWork is on a new Thread, but the ReportProgress is on the UI. Why is there a difference in these two implementations (RestSharp and BackgroundWorker)? Or more, what is the standard for callbacks?

Comment: There are two common patterns for async operations in .net: Asynchronious Programming Model(it emerges in delegates, in IO, in older style webrequsts) In this model callbacks are called in some thread in thread pool. This is well-known model. The newer one in implemented in BackgroundWorker, WebClient and some other few classes(it is called EAP, or something like that, don't remember exact name). In this model callbacks are executed in caller thread. So, RestSharp used EAP model, but provided implementation as APM. Design flaw:)